# Non-overlapped transparent control

Tags: c#, winforms, transparency, topmost, axwindowsmediaplayer

I'm trying to make a tooltip for my video player. I use a windows media player embedded into my winform's app on c# (**AxWMPLib.AxWindowsMediaPlayer**) for playing video. And I have created a control that shows a current position of a media. This control is transparent. Control's code is below:

```cs
namespace player.Controls
{
public partial class TransparentToolTip : System.Windows.Forms.UserControl
{
    public enum PointerLocation : byte { ... }

    #region Private data
     // ...
    #endregion

    Timer Wriggler = new Timer();
    int iInterval = 100;
    protected void TickHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.InvalidateEx();
    } 

    private void _SetStyle()
    {
        this.SetStyle((ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint | ControlStyles.UserPaint | ControlStyles.ResizeRedraw | ControlStyles.CacheText | ControlStyles.ContainerControl), true);
        this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.Selectable, false);
        this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.SupportsTransparentBackColor | ControlStyles.Opaque, true);            
        this.UpdateStyles();
    }
    private void _SetTimer(int _Interval)
    {
        Wriggler.Tick += new EventHandler(TickHandler);
        this.Wriggler.Interval = _Interval;
        this.Wriggler.Enabled = true;
    }    

    public TransparentToolTip()
    {            
        InitializeComponent();
        _SetStyle();
        _SetTimer(iInterval);                    
    }
    public TransparentToolTip(System.ComponentModel.IContainer container)
    {               
        container.Add(this);             
        InitializeComponent();            
        _SetStyle();
        _SetTimer(iInterval); 
    }        

    protected override CreateParams CreateParams
    {
        get
        {
            CreateParams cp = base.CreateParams;
            cp.ExStyle |= (0x00000020 | 0x00000008); // WS_EX_TRANSPARENT  = 0x00000020, WS_EX_TOPMOST = 0x00000008              
            return cp;
        }
    }
    #region Extra Properties
    // ...
    #endregion

    // Drawing            
    protected void InvalidateEx()
    {
        if (Parent == null)
            return;
        Rectangle rc = new Rectangle(this.Location, this.Size);
        Parent.Invalidate(rc, true);
    }
    protected override void OnPaintBackground(PaintEventArgs pevent)
    {

    }
    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs pe)
    {           
        pe.Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
        pe.Graphics.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
        pe.Graphics.TextRenderingHint = System.Drawing.Text.TextRenderingHint.AntiAlias;
        pe.Graphics.PixelOffsetMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;

        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(this.ClientRectangle.X, this.ClientRectangle.Y, this.ClientRectangle.Width - 1, this.ClientRectangle.Height - 1);            
        SolidBrush brushBackground = new SolidBrush(ColorBackground);
        SolidBrush brushBorder = new SolidBrush(ColorBorder);
        using (GraphicsPath graphicsPath = ToolTipBody(...))
        {
            using (Pen p = new Pen(brushBorder, BorderSize))
            {
                pe.Graphics.FillPath(brushBackground, graphicsPath); // background
                pe.Graphics.DrawPath(p, graphicsPath); // borders
            }
        }            

        TextFormatFlags flags = // some flags;
        TextRenderer.DrawText(pe.Graphics, ToolTipText, Font, new Rectangle(this.ClientRectangle.X, this.ClientRectangle.Y, this.ClientRectangle.Width, this.ClientRectangle.Height - TriangleSizeSide), ToolTipColor, System.Drawing.Color.Transparent, flags);
        brushBorder.Dispose();
        brushBackground.Dispose();

        base.OnPaint(pe);
    }
    // Form mapping tips
    private GraphicsPath ToolTipBody(...)
    { 
        // some code
        return graphicsPath;
    }
}
```

I try to show this tooltip over the axWindowsMediaPlayer object. But my control is overlapped by the media player. I've tried to use **SetWindowPos** but this does not work:

```cs
static readonly IntPtr HWND_TOPMOST = new IntPtr(-1);
const int SWP_NOSIZE = 0x0001;
const int SWP_NOMOVE = 0x0002;
const int SWP_SHOWWINDOW = 0x0040;
//...
 [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, ExactSpelling = true)]
 [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
  public static extern bool SetWindowPos(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hWndInsertAfter, int x, int y, int cx, int cy, int flags);
//...
SetWindowPos(transparentToolTip1.Handle, HWND_TOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_SHOWWINDOW);
```

**Note:** If do not change **CreateParams** of a new control it draws over the media player. But it becomes opaque.

Is any ideas to do it correct using [winforms](/questions/tagged/winforms)?

Comment: Please edit your question and provide a meaningful title.

Comment: Please fix the title of the question/

Comment: Sorry. Has already been done.

Comment: This isn't going to work well with a media player.  Tooltips should be toplevel windows anyway.  Easy to get one: derive your class from Form instead using FormBorderStyle = None.  Transparency is now simple with the TransparencyKey property.  It will be too big, adjust its size in the Load event.

Comment: This method is the second of those that I considered (the first one is a custom control). It works very well. Tnx.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that the transparent thing is happening because you're defining the control style as `ControlStyles.Opaque`. Then, setting the flag to `WS_EX_TRANSPARENT` you're setting it to transparent style again.

About the overlapped issue: If you designed the form using the Visual Studio Windows Forms designer, maybe your control is zOrdered down the `AxWMPLib.AxWindowsMediaPlayer` component. Try to [bring to front](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.bringtofront.aspx) or [control the ChildrenIndex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.setchildindex.aspx) in your control collection before show it.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Methods [Control.BringToFront](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.bringtofront.aspx) and [Control.ControlCollection.SetChildIndex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.setchildindex.aspx) do not solve the problem. Custom control is still behind the video. So I've decided to use a custom form with set properties **TransparencyKey** and **Opacity** instead of using a custom control